# how to validate a text box so that it can accept only Arabic letters?

Tags: php, arabic

I have to validate a text box content using PHP, that only accepts Arabic letters as input.

This is the code am using :

```
if (preg_match('/^[\u0600-\u06FF]{6,60}$/', $text)) {
       echo "valid Entry"; 
   } else {
       echo "Invalid Entry";
 }
```

Comment: You show what you've attempted, we'll (maybe) try help fixing it. We're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: don't put code into comments. you can edit the question and put it there.

Comment: new To this .. pardon mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try this for php

```
if(preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u", $name])) {
echo 'valid';
}
```

Try this for javascript

```
function HasArabicCharacters(text)
{
    var arregex = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
    alert(arregex.test(text));
}
```

Refer and find more usefull Arabic PHP Mathods
http://www.ar-php.com

Comment: the java script function cant accept if a English charecter added with it

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is not for only arabic.

Try this one. I checked that it works.

```
function isArabic($str)
{
    if(!preg_match("/^[\s\p{Arabic}]+$/u", $str) ||
       !preg_match('/^[\s\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0750}-\x{077F}\x{08A0}-\x{08FF}\x{FB50}-\x{FDFF}\x{FE70}-\x{FEFF}\x{10E60}\x{10E60}—\x{10E7F}\x{1EE00}—\x{1EEFF}]+$/u', $str))
    {
        echo 'Invalid';
        return false;
    }

    echo 'Valid';
    return true;
}
```

Reference: [How can i allow only arabic characters in input text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565277/how-can-i-allow-only-arabic-characters-in-input-text-field)